# EditText in ListView with windowSoftInputMode adjustPan

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a `ListView` with an `EditText` in each row. I have set `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan` in the manifest for this activity, so when I tap on an `EditText` the layout pans so that it is visible above the keyboard.

This works the first time I tap on an `EditText`. But if I hit the back button to dismiss the keyboard, then tap the same EditText again (without tapping anything else, so the cursor remains in the first `EditText`), the keyboard comes back up but the layout does not pan this time. The result of this is that the `EditText` is obscured behind the keyboard.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour / knows how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a bug to me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Still not sure why this happens, but I have a solution.

I have subclassed `EditText` and overridden the method `onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        clearFocus();
    }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

Now when the back key is pressed, the `EditText` gives up focus. Then tapping it again has the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Matt... Glad I'm not the only one noticing all these anomalies in Android. Still young though...API's in the future will rock. When you got some time, please check out this other fault I picked up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267137/android-adjustpan-not-working-after-edittext-container-has-been-translated Many thanks